# AWS ELB high latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

My website is managed by aws elastic beanstalk. I realized that recently, if I access the website through my domain, it could take up to 15s for the first page to get fetched. While if I use the url in the beanstalk env to access the website, it is almost instant.

The curl result as below:

**<mydomain.com>** note that the **starttransfer** is 15s.

```
curl -kso /dev/null https://<mydomain.com>/ -w "==============\n\n 
| dnslookup: %{time_namelookup}\n 
| connect: %{time_connect}\n 
| appconnect: %{time_appconnect}\n 
| pretransfer: %{time_pretransfer}\n 
| starttransfer: %{time_starttransfer}\n 
| total: %{time_total}\n 
| size: %{size_download}\n 
| HTTPCode=%{http_code}\n\n"
==============

 
| dnslookup: 0.066132
 
| connect: 0.113809
 
| appconnect: 0.227941
 
| pretransfer: 0.228082
 
| starttransfer: 15.680502
 
| total: 15.680691
 
| size: 2569
 
| HTTPCode=200
```

```
 curl -kso /dev/null http://<Beanstalk URL>/ -w "==============\n\n 
> | dnslookup: %{time_namelookup}\n 
> | connect: %{time_connect}\n 
> | appconnect: %{time_appconnect}\n 
> | pretransfer: %{time_pretransfer}\n 
> | starttransfer: %{time_starttransfer}\n 
> | total: %{time_total}\n 
> | size: %{size_download}\n 
> | HTTPCode=%{http_code}\n\n"
==============

 
| dnslookup: 0.005155
 
| connect: 0.055637
 
| appconnect: 0.000000
 
| pretransfer: 0.055709
 
| starttransfer: 0.111385
 
| total: 0.113621
 
| size: 2640
 
| HTTPCode=200
```

So I suspect this is a ELB configuration issue rather than some issue in my server instance. Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked these metrics in CloudWatch to determine the ELB latency, as well as the application latency during the requests? :)

Comment: Did you check if you have a private subnet attached to your ELB by chance? I remember I had an issue like this; the first request took 60 seconds to reach the server through the ALB because there was a private subnet, and a public subnet attached to the ALB. The timeout for a request was also 60 seconds, thus explaining why it took 60 seconds to reach the server.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I have, it does show the latency for 15 seconds for a request, which I have no idea.